How do i link a header file to C code file
Some time ago, I decided to start learning C.  I decided that doing Harvard's CS50 would be a great start.  The problem is that they use their own header file in their code, which is named cs50.h, and I don't really know how to link it to my code.  I primarily use Vim and do everything from the console.  Currently, my main pc broke so instead of coding on Linux, I've been using Windows's MSYS2. I would be grateful for any feedback and also if someone could send me some theory behind this: what are header files, how do they work, how to link them to code and overall theory behind this so I could understand the topic much better than I do currently which is almost nothing.
#include "include/cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int n = get_size();

        print_grid(n);
}

int get_size(void)
{
        int n;

        do
        {
                n = get_int("Size: ");
        }

        while (n < 1);
        return n;
}

void print_grid(int size)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                        printf("#");
                }

                printf("\n");
        }
}

When it comes to how my files look it looks like this:
CS50/main.c
CS50/include/cs50.h

I also have been trying to compile it in different ways, normally with the use of only stdio.h, i do it like this:
gcc -o main main.c

but I also did something like this:
gcc -o main main.c -iInclude

if I remember correctly.
Error:
$ gcc -o main main.c -lcs50

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘get_size’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    6 |         int n = get_size();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
main.c:8:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print_grid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    8 |         print_grid(n);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
main.c: At top level:
main.c:24:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘print_grid’; have ‘void(int)’
   24 | void print_grid(int size)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.c:8:9: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘print_grid’ with type ‘void(int)’
    8 |         print_grid(n);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lcs50: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Please edit your question and show the command line used to compile and the error output from the compilation.

I added the picture of the error and what i tried to compile it with, thanks for feedback!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Also, you're basically asking someone to write a tutorial on C programming for you, which is not how SO works. There are many good tutorials and books available on programming in C, all of which explain the several questions you have about header files and how to use them.

Is there anything you would recommend specifically for this topic? I would greatly appreciate it, thanks for feedback!

Try to write int get_size(void) and void print_grid(int size) functions on the upper side of main function instead of below. I would recommend to look at function declaration in c

Feedback: "Harward's" is actually "Harvard's". There's a confusion, too, between 'i' and 'I' in your writing, and what is a phrase and what is a sentence... First suggestion is to start to pay attention to details like this. Otherwise, C will be unforgiving toward a too-casual approach to coding...

Welcome to SO. For better understanding and less confusion in future discussions, you need to get your wording correct. You do not link header files. You include header files. Including a header is job of the preprocessor during compilation. That means, the content of the header is basically copied into your C file and then the compiler runs over it. Linking is a job of the linker. It collects the result of different compilation runs and puts it together to an executable. You link with other object files or with libraries. That is very different from including a file.

That beind said, your error is not related to any of both. It is due to the lack of a declaration before you use a function.

In c a header file is used during (pre)compilation to include definitions of types , functions, … you do not link an header file : you compile the c files containing the implementation code as obj files and link these to the compiled main c file to produced the executable program.

In addition to adding prototypes for your own functions, you will need to link with the cs50 library to get functions like get_int(). The CS50 course notes should show how to do this.

Ok so basically, my stupid ass thought that all you need to use a library is a header file, so all i did was include the header file and not the C file with actual functions and other stuff. I also got a problem later when i did include thye C file but that was just because i forgot to install core essentials for C.

I think the main problem is that you seem to be going mainly by trial & error instead of using some structured course work that would teach you proper basics. Personally, I also dislike learning those basics using "helpers" like cs50.h.
